# Why Floating Point Exception(Linux)

Tags: c

I am getting Floating Point Exception when i run this program on Linux.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int num, num1, num2, n, i, j = 0, t, count = 0;
    int root;

    printf("Enter number of test cases\n");
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (j < t)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        root = (int)sqrt(num);
        for (i = 1; i < root; i++)
        {
            printf("Inside for");
            if (num % i == 0)
                num1 = i;
            while (num1 > 0)
            {
                n = num1 % 10;
                num1 = num1 / 10;
                if (n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 6)
                    count++;
            }
            if (num % num1 == 0)
            {
                num2 = (int)num / num1;
                while (num2 > 0)
                {
                    n = num2 % 10;
                    num2 = num2 / 10;
                    if (n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 6)
                        count++;
                }
            }
        }
        j++;
        count = 0;
        printf("%d", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to correct it

Comment: You might want to indent your code, it will be much more easier to read then.

Comment: It would help if you could properly indent your code and maybe determine at which line the program crashes.

Comment: The only place you use floating point is the `sqrt` call. When the exception happen, what is the value of `num`?

Comment: @mbratch20 int will automatically be converted by the compiler.

Comment: In `num % num1`, if `num1` is 0 (you exit the loop when it becomes zero, so that's more or less an expected case), you divide by zero. Linux is silly and calls that a floating point exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a debugger:

```
Starting program: /home/david/demo 
Enter number of test cases
2
10

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x000000000040076d in main () at demo.c:26
26              if (num % num1 == 0)
(gdb) p num1
$1 = 0
(gdb)
```

As you can see, the value of `num1` is 0, division by 0

Answer (score 1):

```
    while (num1 > 0)
    {
        n = num1 % 10;
        num1 = num1 / 10;
        if (n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 6)
            count++;
    }
    if (num % num1 == 0)
```

You rolling loop unless num1 becomes 0, then dividing by zero. Division by zero is guaranteed SIGFPE (at least on x86 and amd64). Despite name, it have nothing to do with floating point numbers.

Comment: `SIGFPE` is a Unix/Posix signal, not an x86 or ARM requirement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sure thing. Not sure if it is _required_ to trigger when dividing by zero on other CPUs, tho - that's why remark. And there are many other things where SIGFPE could happen, but it results just a quiet NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Print the value of num1 before % operation, it gets 0 and then you exception of division by 0